# Parallel testing in rails 6 and rspec

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, parallel-testing

I am trying to make parallel tests using rspec and rails 6.
According to their documentation, it is just required to add PARALLEL_WORKERS=15 where 15 is the number of workers. However, this works for Testcases and not for rspecs.

Have anybody found a solution to make it works with rspec?

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#parallel-testing

Comment: Not 100% sure, but it looks like SimpleTest is the only one that supports this official way of parallelizing specs (as this is default testing framework for rails). For RSpec consider using a gem like: https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests

Answer (score 1):

The `parrallel tests` gem does that:

- https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests

> Speedup Minitest + RSpec + Turnip + Cucumber + Spinach by running
> parallel on multiple CPU cores. ParallelTests splits tests into
> balanced groups (by number of lines or runtime) and runs each group in
> a process with its own database.

Comment: `parallel_tests` gem looks interesting considering RSpec does support Rails 6 built-in parallel testing.  The issue is tracked here: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/2104

Answer (score 0):

RSpec does not support Rails 6 built-in parallel testing.

https://oozou.com/blog/running-specs-in-parallel-before-rails-6-84

#rspec #rubyonrails #rails6

Comment: Your link implies that it is supported.